# Graph in chart with x without limits

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I have defined a chart on a form, as you are entering the data the chart gets smaller.
Is there any way to make it pass the data as an infinite tape, doing that all entries completed within the limits of chart?

y as any series of numbers, in this case is electric current
x are time in seconds

I need the x pass continuously, not acumulative from the y and x = 0

Answer (score 0):

Get the Visual Studio 2010 "WinFormsChartSamples" at Microsoft's web page [Samples Environment for .NET Framework 4 Chart Controls Released!](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart)

In the example charts, there are live signal-type and time-series charts which show the real-time signal move to the left as the data are fed to the chart.  Also, several speed options are available.